# Where can I get Android 2.2 (API 8) emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-2.2-froyo

I need to debug an applications I'm writing on Android API 8 but I can't find it on Android SDK manager.
I only have SDK Platform, Samples for SDK and Google APIs.

Where can I get it?

Comment: If you have SDK platform for API 8 then tick on it and install it... :).. as u said u have it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you load up the SDK manager you will see a list of available android versions.

Tick the one that you want followed by install.

Then go to the AVD manager and create a new emulator and select API Android 2.2 as the OS for the device.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I also needed the system image

Comment: I believe the SDK platform checkbox is what installs the system image. If you go to where the SDK is installed and then go into platforms there will be a directory called android-<api> in there contains the system image

Answer (score 2):

open eclipse >>window >> Android sdk manager >> and check mark api level 8 and download it then create new emulater and select API level 8 .[image]
 [image]